# HTTP websites vs HTTPS websites

Tags: http, websites, http2

Why do we say that an `http` website is not secure compared to an `https` website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websites using the http protocol only do not provide any protection. On the other hand webpages using th https protol (s stands for secure) typically use SSL or TLS protocol to encrypt communications. Both of those protocols are PKI methods of encryption. Each of the two parties that communicate have a public and a private key of encryption. When A wants to contact B securely, he uses B's public key to encrypt his message. That message can only be decrypted (when one does not take in mind cyber attacks) by B's private key. And visa versa.

Check this and just google it you will find a lot more info depending on how deeply you want to understand the concept.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure

Answer (score 6):

HTTP simply has no security mechanisms. Everything you communicate via HTTP can be read and modified by anyone who handles the data - it's just like sending a postcard.

HTTPS was created as a reaction to that. It's a wrapper around HTTP that adds SSL/TLS encryption without altering the HTTP protocol itself.

HTTPS *adds* security to HTTP just as you *add* a lock to your door. You shouldn't think of it as an alternative protocol that just happens to be "comparatively more secure".